# Android assest folder image attachment to email failed

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a mail attaching assest folder image to the mail, mail is sent successfully, but when i checked it there was no image attached to the mail,
this is my code,

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///android_asset/Hat_5.png"));

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[] { "some@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "New Order");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Order Id :" +imageId);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only attach files from the SDCARD.
You'll need to copy the image to the SDCARD and change the URI the the file's path on the sdcard.
You could delete if afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want

```
String FILENAME = "avatar.png";
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("","FileNotFoundException: "+e1.getMessage());

    }

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");


        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
            fos.write(buf,0,len);
        fos.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("","IOException: "+e1.getMessage());

    }

    // Get the file from internal storage

    String filePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();//returns current directory.
    File file = new File(filePath, FILENAME);
```

then

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM  , uri);
```

And send the attachment...